# Replace element name with string

Tags: jquery, string

Replace an element name in a string fails. replace() doesn't seem working.

```
var a = 1;

function generateDiv() { 
    a++;
    var firstDiv = $(".firstDiv").html();
    firstDiv.replace("fileName1", "fileName" + a);  
    $('#mainDiv').append(firstDiv);
}
```

Comment: can you show the html as well?

Comment: `firstDiv = firstDiv.replace("fileName1","fileName"+a)`

Comment: Note that instead of amending the HTML string (which could lead to unexpected changes if you have the name repeated elsewhere in the code) you could just `clone()` the elements and change the `name` property of the required element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the variable value, `replace()` will return the new string and it will not update the variable.

```js
var a = 1;

function generateDiv() {
  a++;
  var firstDiv = $(".firstDiv").html();
  firstDiv = firstDiv.replace("fileName1", "fileName" + a); // update the variable with returned value
  // or do it in single line
  // var firstDiv = $(".firstDiv").html().replace("fileName1", "fileName" + a);  
  $('#mainDiv').append(firstDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace returns replaced string, it is not replaces variable... so please do it like

```
firstDiv = firstDiv.replace("fileName1", "fileName" + a);
```